# logback configure for file and stdout

Tags: spring-boot, logback

How cad I configure logback.xml for file and stdout? With thos only I have file.

```
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Comment: You can add additinal `appender-ref` tag. 
`<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>`

Comment: Thanks, it woks fine

Comment: Great mark as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional `appender-ref` tag.

```
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
```